# La biblioteca win32 no esta reconocida a pesar de haberla instalado

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, librería, scrapy

Intenté hacer un proyecto con in Scrapy scraper, que funcionó bien hasta ahora, desder cero. Pero esta vez me parece que necesito una librería `win32api`. Puede que lo haya instalado en mi entorno virtual, pero me siempre no lo reconoce.

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Tests\bass2\scraper>python -m pip install win32api
Collecting win32api
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32api (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for win32api
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Tests\bass2\scraper>scrapy crawl sephora -o perfumes.json
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7
:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 13:35:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.2.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-S
P0
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'nosetime_scraper',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 7,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'nosetime_scraper.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['nosetime_scraper.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
               'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 '
               'Safari/537.36'}
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 16ea497e99400f83
2021-01-18 10:45:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-01-18 10:45:57 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers] ERROR: Loading "scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http.HTTPDownloadHandler" for scheme "http"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 49, in _load_handler
    dhcls = load_object(path)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11 import (
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
2021-01-18 10:45:57 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers] ERROR: Loading "scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http.HTTPDownloadHandler" for scheme "https"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 49, in _load_handler
    dhcls = load_object(path)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11 import (
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
2021-01-18 10:45:57 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers] ERROR: Loading "scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3.S3DownloadHandler" for scheme "s3"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 49, in _load_handler
    dhcls = load_object(path)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\s3.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http import HTTPDownloadHandler
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11 import (
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2021-01-18 10:45:57 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 192, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 196, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\retry.py", line 24, in <module>
    from twisted.web.client import ResponseFailed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint, wrapClientTLS
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

2021-01-18 10:45:57 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\retry.py", line 24, in <module>
    from twisted.web.client import ResponseFailed
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint, wrapClientTLS
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 41, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
```

Tambien instalé `pypiwin32`:

```
(scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Tests\bass2\scraper>python -m pip install pypiwin32
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\tests\bass2\scraper\scr_env\lib\site-packages (223)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\tests\bass2\scraper\scr_env\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32) (300)
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Pero me da el mismo error.

Comment: no creo que sea la causa, pero deberias actualizar `pip`

Answer (score 1):

El nombre de la librería es `pywin32`. Deberías instalarla con `pip install pywin32`

*Nota: en el caso concreto de la pregunta de @revolucion-for-monica existía un problema de dependencias en los requisitos de la solución. Queda anotado en [la siguiente conversación](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118587/discussion-between-cesar-gonzalez-and-revolucion-for-monica)*

Comment: Hola caballero César, desafortunadamente esta librería no existe.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/

Comment: Mil disculpas de hecho. Desafortunadamente después de la instalación el error sigue siendo el mismo. El requisito ya satisfecho: `Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223` como puede verlo en la última muestra de código.

Comment: por curiosidad:el scraper lo tienes funcionando como servidor?

Comment: La arquitectura del proyecto Scrapy se construye alrededor de "arañas", que son orugas autónomas a las que se les da un conjunto de instrucciones.

Comment: Por ser un poco más concreto: estás utilizando scrapyd para desplegar las arañas? Por otro lado, te has asegurado de reiniciar scrapy después de instalar pywin32? En situaciones similares de tener que añadir dependencias he tenido que volver a generar las arañas para que detecte los cambios en site-packages, lo mismo el problema viene de ahí

Comment: Interesante utiliso: `scrapy crawl <nombre_de_la_arana_> -o doc.json`. Como haces para volver a generar las arañas?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118587/discussion-between-cesar-gonzalez-and-revolucion-for-monica).